# Facebook profile picture URL stops working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created an app with react native, where the user is able to log in with facebook. I request the users `first_name`, `last_name` and `picture.width(520)`(which is the users profile picture).

When the user log ins for the first time it works fine. In the profile section you can actually see the picture, however after a day or so if you log in again the profile picture wont load. In the database I can still see the same URL given to me by the request, it just wont load.

Does FB change the URL or how can I permanently get a URL that points to the users profile picture?

The actual request:

```
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me',
  {
    parameters: {
      fields: {
          string: 'first_name,last_name,picture.width(520)'
        }
      }
  }, (error, result) => {

  //save picture URL to database

})
```

Comment: Yes, those URLs are to be considered transient, you should not store them for long-time use. If you don’t want to make API requests for this all the time, then simply use the redirect version directly as image src wherever you want to show it.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the help! Can you elaborate on how I can get the redirect version?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/{app-scoped_user_id}/picture?width=520`

Comment: @CBroe this means that if the user changes his facebook profile picture it will also change in my app right? There is no way to make the current picture permanent, wether the user changes his picture or not?

Comment: Yes, it automatically redirects to the current one. And you are not supposed to show older pictures, at least not in any profile-type of context - that should always be the current one, that’s how the user chose to present themself at this time after all. (Accessing a user’s profile pictures album and listing the photos for some purpose would be a different thing.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much!